# Set Catalog / Cart Price Rule

Tags: price, magento-1.6, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

I need to set up a this Price Rule:

(a selected category, for example a Brand)

> 100-299 $ = 10% Discount
>   300-499 $ = 12% Discount
>   500-999 $ = 15% Discount
>   over 1000 $ = 20% Discount

I tried in Magento 1.6, but in Catalog Price Rule its not possible to set the PRICE and in the Cart Price Rule its not possible to choose the CATEGORY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with a Shopping Cart PRice Rule using product subselections. Set this rule:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    If total amount  equals or greater than  100  for a subselection of items
    in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
        Category  is  Xyz  

    If total amount  equals or less than  299  for a subselection of items
    in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
        Category  is  Xyz
```